# How to develop new site with Sage Pay

Tags: opayo

**Note: Not sure if this is the best site for this question but didn't think it was suitable for Super User etc.**

I have a client with an e-commerce site built using Sage Pay. I am in the process of developing their brand new website which will also be using Sage Pay.

I am aware that if you run any transactions on the test Sage Pay server your Sage Pay account will stop taking payments. See ***'If you are already set up on Live and are testing additional functionality, DO NOT leave your kit set to Test or you will not receive any money for your transactions!'*** from the Sage Pay docs.

My question is how can I develop my integration with Sage Pay in a safe environment which won't have any detrimental effects on the clients live Sage Pay site.

The Sage Pay simulator sounds perfect for what I am trying to do but this has not been updated to use the current protocol and I've been told there is no release date as of yet for the new version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the quote above is from one of the comments in the integration kit. Essentially, it is a warning that if you change your integration, to point at the Sage Pay test server, you won't be taking much in the way of payments.....

As long as you have a *separate* test integration, pointing at the Sage Pay test server, the production site will continue to operate as usual.

The test and live accounts aren't linked - the live environment won't know (or care) that there are test transactions being made from another integration.

Comment: Well that's embaressing, thanks for explaining that to me. Not sure how i misread that but better to be safe than sorry I guess. cheers.